# Media manager asks for file title when upload

Tags: uploads, media-library

When I upload a new file I have this error message : Content, title, and excerpt are empty.

I found the error messahe in `wordpress_data/wp-content/languages/en_GB.po` line 6809 (but it's a post related file !)

The file is physcially uploaded, but it's not shown on media lits.

I have no hints in wp-content/debug.log :

```php
define('WP_CACHE', false);
define('DISABLE_CACHE', true);
define('WP_REDIS_DISABLED', true);
```

I'm using WP 6.1.3 multsite on PHP 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Line 4139 of `post.php` in WP 6.2 branch](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/6.2/src/wp-includes/post.php#L4139) has the error message, `Content, title, and excerpt are empty.`. Reviewing the previous lines of code, it should be excluded for attachments, but there may be a callback applied to [the `wp_insert_post_empty_content` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_insert_post_empty_content/) which is requiring attachments to also have content, title, and excerpt.

Use [Query Monitor](https://querymonitor.com/) or search your codebase for uses of the `wp_insert_post_empty_content` filter. If none are found, then you can use the second parameter of the filter to restore core functionality on the filter (untested):

```php
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_empty_content', static function ( $maybe_empty, $postarr ) {
    $post_type    = empty( $postarr['post_type'] ) ? 'post' : $postarr['post_type'];
    $post_title   = $postarr['post_title'];
    $post_content = $postarr['post_content'];
    $post_excerpt = $postarr['post_excerpt']; 

    return 'attachment' !== $post_type
        && ! $post_content && ! $post_title && ! $post_excerpt
        && post_type_supports( $post_type, 'editor' )
        && post_type_supports( $post_type, 'title' )
        && post_type_supports( $post_type, 'excerpt' );
}, 9999, 2 );
```

Comment: Thanks :) There was a plugin with `wp_insert_post_empty_content` hook ! I've removed it and it's ok.